# Preserve unsaved files when Sublime Text 3 application is closed

Tags: notepad++, sublime-text-3

I was working with Notepad++ on Windows, and now I use Mac. So, I can no longer use Notepad++, and I switched to Sublime Text 3.

In Notepad++ there is a feature that I used with unsaved files. When I closed the application, it did not require that the files were saved, and the unsaved files were reopened when I opened Notepad++ again.

With the default configuration in Sublime Text 3, I don't see that feature. Is it supported in Sublime Text 3? If it exists, how to configure it?

Comment: see this forum post for an explanation of what is happening on a Mac: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/about-windows/25413/4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `hot_exit` setting.

Since I'm running Sublime Text 3 (Build 3126), in Windows 10 Pro, I can't say for sure if this will work exactly the same for you, but the steps in Windows are as follows:

1. Click `Preferences -> Settings`
2. In the new dual-pane window that opens, the tab on the right is labeled `Preferences.sublime-settings-User`. If that file does not contain any text, just paste the following, save the file, and close it:

   ```
   {
       "hot_exit": true
   }
   ```

If that file already contains text, either change the value of the existing `hot_exit` setting from `false` to `true`, or add the `"hot_exit": true` line above (without the curly braces). Use commas to separate that line from the lines immediately before and after it. For more information on working with Settings in Sublime Text 3, see the [documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/settings.html).

Here's the full description of the `hot_exit` setting, from the `Preferences.sublime-settings-Default` file (which should not be modified, that's why the above-mentioned `Preferences.sublime-settings-User` file exists):

```
// Exiting the application with hot_exit enabled will cause it to close
// immediately without prompting. Unsaved modifications and open files will
// be preserved and restored when next starting.
//
// Closing a window with an associated project will also close the window
// without prompting, preserving unsaved changes in the workspace file
// alongside the project.
```

Comment: hi, I apply your solution and see that you I quit sublime the file save and restore when I turn on but if I use close button it still show dialog save. Can I add that feature (I want to when I use close button of sublime it close and no dialog, save all file working)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking.  Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: if I quit program file save and restore but I close window it show dialog save. I don't want to show the dialog (same with notepad++). Sorry for my English.

Comment: What action are you taking to "quit program file", and what action are you taking to "close window"?

Comment: It is quit sublimt an close window. quit sublime: sublime Text > Quit Sublime Text, close window: File > Close window.

Comment: I don't think I can help you there, as I don't seem to have any option like `sublime Text > Quit Sublime Text`. On my Windows 10 Pro machine, I can think of three different ways to close the ST3 application: 1. Click `File -> Exit`; 2. Click the `X` icon in the top-right corner of the window; 3. Press `Alt+F4` on the keyboard.  In all three cases, ST3 closes without any prompt to save open files, and restores the open files when I launch ST3 again. You might consider posting a new question on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hi, there are something difference between Mac and Window, on Mac when I close window the program not exist. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: On Linux (Linux Mint) it can happen that the session file isn't owned by the user, therefor those settings won't take effect (happened to me). Solution is to chmod the Session.sublime_session file to your user. see https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/change-log-pop-up-always-show-at-run-3143-version-on-linux/31801/5

Answer (score 1):

instead of clicking on red close button, right click on dock and quit the application. It will preserve the unsaved files

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thanks @user1777660